# Typescript: Why doesn't typeguard work with previous state

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, typeguards

When making a simple rock, paper, scissors game with typescript I cam across an interaction I couldn't understand.

```
const [gameState, setGameState] = useState<gameState>({
    choice: null,
    score: 0,
  });

function fetchScore() {
    let score = localStorage.getItem("score");
    if (typeof score === "string") {
      setGameState((prev) => ({ ...prev, score: 
      parseInt(score) })); // Typescript still thinks score can be null
    } 
}
```

parseInt throws an error saying score could be set to null despite the type guard.

I did some messing around and found that it was only happening when I used prev state.

```
 const [test,setTest] = useState(0);

 function fetchScore() {
    let score = localStorage.getItem("score");
    if (typeof score === "string") {
      setTest(parseInt(score))//Score is correctly guarded
    } 
  }
```

I am currently handling it by typecasting score as a string but I would like to understand what cause this to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you are using score inside of a callback function. So typescript assumes that `score` variable can be changed before callback function will be executed and score potentially can null inside callback function.
Solutions:
the best solution I see is to use `const` instead of `let`.

```
const score = localStorage.getItem("score");
```

this way typescript know that score cannot be changed later.

Also you could check `typeof score` inside of callback function and typescript will not complaine. I would prefer `const`. But this will work too. Just for understanding how it works here:

```
function fetchScore() {
  let score = localStorage.getItem("score");
  setGameState((prev: any) => {
    if (typeof score === "string") {
      // no complaining, checking inside of callback function
      return { ...prev, score: parseInt(score) };
    }
    return prev;
  });
}
```